# How to divide one row in various?

Tags: jquery, postgresql, select

I have a column `data` in a postgresql table that receive data like this: `|A|C|F|L|T|U|`

The others columns are `name, date`

Example:

```
NAME    | DATE       | DATA
ALYSSON | 2019-01-01 | |A|B|C|
```

How to create a select that return:

```
NAME    | DATE       | DATA
ALYSSON | 2019-01-01 | A
ALYSSON | 2019-01-01 | B
ALYSSON | 2019-01-01 | C
```

Comment: You want to do that at the postgres level or at the javascript level. If you want to do that at the javascript level, how that response looks like(assuming that is json)

Comment: @Hackerman postgres level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string_to_array along with unnest to break your data into first an array and then separate rows.

```
select * FROM (
  select name, date, unnest(string_to_array(data, '|')) as data from stuff
) AS sub
WHERE sub.data != '';
```

The WHERE clause is required to remove the empty strings at the beginning and end of your data.